# How to cancel a scheduled Quartz job in Spring

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Spring to inject a Quartz scheduler (abstracted with Spring's TaskScheduler interface) into my app that loads jobs configured from a database at startup.

It adds each job in the scheduler something like this:

```
TaskScheduler taskScheduler = ...;//injected    
Runnable runableThing = ...;
String cronExpression = ...; //from DB
taskScheduler.schedule(runableThing, new CronTrigger(cronExpression));
```

my question is this: Is it possible to specify something like a job_id that can subsequently be used to cancel the job/trigger - say in response to a user selecting the job to be cancelled in the web interface?

I've looked at the Spring docs and can't see a way to do this.

Any ideas gratefully received.

Comment: Thanks to 'matt b' and 'Puspendu Banerjee' for this answer. I hadn't noticed the cookbook examples - really useful.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Unscheduling a Particular Trigger of Job

```
scheduler.unscheduleJob(triggerName, triggerGroup);
```

Deleting a Job and Unscheduling All of Its Triggers

```
scheduler.deleteJob(jobName, jobGroup);
```

Ref: http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz/wikidocs/UnscheduleJob.html

Comment: He was asking about the Spring `org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler`. Your examples refer to the native Quartz scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

```
ScheduledFuture<V> job = taskSchedule.schedule(runableThing, new CronTrigger(cronExpression))
job.cancel(true);
```